# SQL - Add constraint with foreign key in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreign-keys, constraints

I try to add a constraint but I don't manage to do what I want :).

So in my case, I have these 3 tables :

```
[dbo].[User](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Language] [nvarchar](2) NOT NULL,
    [FirstName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Surname] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    ...
)

[dbo].[Project](
    [Id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [UserId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [KindOfProjectId] [int] NOT NULL,
    ...
)

[dbo].[KindOfProject](
    [Id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Language] [nvarchar](2) NOT NULL,
    ...
 CONSTRAINT [PK__KindOfProject] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC,
    [Language] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
)
```

The table KindOfProject has columns "Id" AND "Language" as Primary Key

And I have added a first constraint to link table Project with table User like this :

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Project]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Project_UserId] FOREIGN KEY([UserId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[User] ([Id])
```

Now, what I want to do is to add a constraint to link the column "KindOfProjectId" from table Project to the column "Id" from table KindOfProject :

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Project]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Project_KindOfProjectId] FOREIGN KEY([KindOfProjectId],[Language]) 
REFERENCES [dbo].[KindOfProject] ([Id],[Language])
```

But it does not work, as there is no column Language in table Project. But I can get it thanks to the link with the table User, as table User has a column Language.

So I have tried something like that :

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Project]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Project_KindOfProjectId] FOREIGN KEY([KindOfProjectId],[User].[Language]) 
    REFERENCES [dbo].[KindOfProject] ([Id],[Language])
```

But nothing works.

Have you an idea about it ? :D

Thanks for your help !

Comment: What database product are you using? In most of them, you'd have to add `language` to `Project` to do everything via DRI. In many, you could create a view that pulls all columns bar `language` from `Project` and have your users use the view rather than the table. Some triggers could then deal with populating the column appropriately.

Comment: You might want to re-think your design. I don't think you can do something like that with foreign keys. The simplest solution is probably to add a surrogate key to the `KindOfProject` table and simply link to it.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you added language to a primary key?

Comment: Thanks for your both answer, I though it would be possible. So I will do some change in my design :)